# How to style 3 (div) boxes using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en">   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleBox.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>   </head>   <body>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
            text
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>   </body> </html>
```

This page should look like this - http://pasteboard.co/nFlMljzPG.png

I have tried something, but I do not know hot to style text inside third div
But without editing the HTML page

my css:

```
div {
    width: 380px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #B0CDE9;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
}

div div {
    width: 290px;
    height: 280px;
    background: yellow;
    margin-left: 45px;
    margin-top: 8px;
}

div div div {
    width: 120px;
    height: 140px;
    background: #82C940;
    margin-top: 70px;

}
```

(my boxes are - http://pasteboard.co/nFo7mv7R7.png ) Could you advise me something please?

Comment: You need to use IDs or classes.

Comment: @Stepan: Can you show your CSS ?

Comment: @Stepan: How exactly do you want to position the text? Center aligned? If not, then you could just add padding in the third div.. or you could also put the text inside a span element and adjust that span element's position with CSS.

Comment: I have added CSS, it is possible to style it without ID's or classes, but I have no idea how

Comment: Yes, padding is good idea!

Comment: wait.. if you add padding the third div's size will increase.. instead you should put the text in a span.. see the answer below.

Comment: Problem is that I mustn't change the HTML page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't want to change the HTML code, you can just apply padding to the third div to position the text inside it. But you need to adjust the width and height of the div when you add padding. For example, if your div has a width of 120 px and you want the text to be 20px away from the left border, so you give a left padding of 20px and decrease the width by 20px. Thus, now you have a div with width 100px and padding left 20px. See the example below.

HTML

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
       text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    width: 380px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #B0CDE9;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
}

div div {
    width: 290px;
    height: 280px;
    background: yellow;
    margin-left: 45px;
    margin-top: 8px;
}

div div div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    background: #82C940;
    margin-top: 70px;
    padding-top:80px;
    padding-left:20px;
}
```

Comment: @Stepan: Then using padding would be a possible solution.. see the edited answer above.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I need

Answer (score 0):

You need to use class or id to be able to style each and every `div` **CLEANLY**

**Maybe this is what you need.**

```css
.outter{
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: orangered;
  border: 5px solid orange;

}

.center{
  height: 50%;
  width: 70%;
  background: blue;
  border: 5px solid grey;
  margin: 10% auto;

}
.inner{
  height: 50%;
  width: 70%;
  background: maroon;
  border: 5px solid white;
  margin: 20% auto;

}
.inner p{
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: serif;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class='outter'>
  <div class='center'>
  
  <div class='inner'>
  <p>This is the text in the inner div</p>
  
  </div>
  
    
  </div>
  
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but problem is that I mustn't change the HTML page

Answer (score 0):

```css
 .blue_div{
  width: 30%;
  background: blue;
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-top: 10%;
  border: thin black solid;
  height: 500px;
 }

 .blue_div .yellow_div{
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 450px;
  background: yellow;
  border: thin black solid;
  margin-top: 5%;
 }


 .blue_div .yellow_div .text_div{
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
  border: thick black solid;
  margin-top: 25%;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 200px;
 }

 .text_div span{

  color: #000000;
  
 }
```

```html
<div class="blue_div">

<div class="yellow_div">
<div class="text_div">
<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Text</span>
 
</div>

</div>
```

Is this the same that you want?

PS : Change **CSS** as per your need.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but problem is that I mustn't change the HTML page